# attempting to parse application/vnd.wap.mms-message file from MMSC

Tags: android, parsing, mms, wap

I'm attempting to properly parse MMS content that is directly downloaded from the MMS Center (this particular MMSC is T-mobile's)

I thought this file type was of 'application/vnd.wap.mms-message' but it doesn't appear to parse correctly.  When I use VIM to open the file contents I see some characters that are readable..

```
�����mavodi-7-89-ef-2-7a-593d0564-248ee16e1ff^@�^DX^Z�^X�+18285550000/TYPE=PLMN^@�^X�+18285550000/TYPE=PLMN^@��������^A^N��E��123_1.jpeg^@����^@^PJFIF^@^A^B^@^@^A^@^A^@^@��^@^D*^@��^K�ICC_PROFILE^@^A^A^@^@^K�^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@mntrRGB XYZ ^G�^@^C^@^[^@^U^@$^@^_acsp^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@��^@^A^@^@^@^@�-^@^@^@^@)�=ޯ�U�xB��ʃ9^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^Pdesc^@^@^AD^@^@^@ybXYZ^@^@^A�^@^@^@^TbTRC^@^@^A�^@^@^H^Ldmdd^@^@ �^@^@^@�gXYZ^@^@h^@^@^@^TgTRC^@^@^A�^@^@^H^Llumi^@^@|^@^@^@^Tmeas^@^@�^@^@^@$bkpt^@^@�^@^@^@^TrXYZ^@^@�^@^@^@^TrTRC^@^@^A�^@^@^H^Ltech^@^@�^@^@^@^Lvued^@^@�^@^@^@�wtpt^@^@^Kp^@^@^@^Tcprt^@^@^K�^@^@^@7chad^@^@^K�^@^@^@,desc^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^_sRGB IEC61966-2-1 black scaled
```

Any help in understanding how to read the image content from the MMS file or insight into what file type is being served up from T-Mobile's MMSC would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi,  Did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue.